# Min/Max/Step function and "body of constexpr function ... not a return-statement"

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I'm catching an error when trying to decorate with `consexpr`:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cxx -o test.exe
test.cxx: In instantiation of ‘static constexpr unsigned int MinMaxStep<min, max
, step>::ValidValue(unsigned int) [with unsigned int min = 10u; unsigned int max
 = 100u; unsigned int step = 10u]’:
test.cxx:22:40:   required from here
test.cxx:16:5: error: body of constexpr function ‘static constexpr unsigned int 
MinMaxStep<min, max, step>::ValidValue(unsigned int) [with unsigned int min = 10
u; unsigned int max = 100u; unsigned int step = 10u]’ not a return-statement
     }
     ^
```

All of the values used in the problem function are template parameters. The values don't change after the file is saved.

Is it not possible to express this as a `constexpr` function?

If I am doing something wrong, then what is it? How do I modify `ValidVaue` into a `constexpr` function?

---

```cxx
$ cat -n test.cxx
 1  #include <string>
 2  #include <iostream>
 3  
 4  template <unsigned int min, unsigned int max, unsigned int step>
 5  class MinMaxStep
 6  {
 7  public:
 8      static constexpr unsigned int Min() { return min; }
 9      static constexpr unsigned int Max() { return max; }
10      static constexpr unsigned int Step() { return step; }
11      static constexpr unsigned int ValidValue(unsigned int v)
12      {
13          if (v <= min) { return min; }
14          else if (v >= max) { return max; }
15          return (v+step-1) - ((v+step-1)%step);
16      }
17  };
18  
19  int main (int argc, char* argv[])
20  {
21      MinMaxStep<10, 100, 10> mms;
22      unsigned int x = mms.ValidValue (18);
23      std::cout << "value " << x << std::endl;
24  
25      return 0;
26  }
```

Comment: `return v <= min ? min : (v >= max ? max : ((v+step-1) - ((v+step-1)%step)));`

Comment: One return statement with ternary operators was accepted. Do you know if its accepted by all the major compilers (Clang, Comeau, GCC, ICC, MSVC and SunCC)? Do any of them have a half baked implementation that you are aware?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rules for `constexpr` functions were very strict in C++11. For example there could be *only* a `return` statement, nothing else. The rules were relaxed considerably in C++14.

See e.g. [this `constexpr` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) for more information.

There are two ways for you to solve your problem: The easiest is to use C++14 instead (change compiler flag to use `-std=c++14`). The other solution is to refactor your `ValidValue` function to only have one single statement, a `return` statement, using the ternary operator.

Comment: Lol... C++14 is out of the question. We live in a special hell at times. We support GCC 3 on Fedora 1 and Visual Studio .Net on Windows 2000 up through anything found today.

Comment: @jww : And yet `constexpr` is still an option for you? o_O

Comment: @ildjarn - Yes, `constxpr`, like other keywords such as `noexcept` or `alignas`, can be abstracted away [in a macro](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/config.h#L923). I can't make an old compiler accept new flags :)